# All the IIS sites are already configured by some other version of ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

We recently did an update to 2016 for ColdFusion. After the update my application was not working. It shows **Access Forbidden** error. I checked the `WS.config` file to see if ColdFusion and IIS are connected. At that time I could see it was empty. When I tried to add it then it shows the error **All the IIS sites are already configured by some other version of ColdFusion**.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

[image: Server Error]

[image: Web Server Configuration]

[image: Warning Message]

Comment: Can you try to remove the handler mapping from the service level in IIS?

Comment: Maybe you can try to configure it manually. Here are instructions on how to configure the IIS web connector manually - [IIS manual connector configuration | Adobe ColdFusion](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-iis-manual-connector-configuration.html)

Comment: Adobe provides free support with CF installations by emailing cf.install@adobe.com.

Comment: There are various states that your Connector configuration could be left in, depending upon which version(s) of Coldfusion you were upgrading from, and how it was previously installed. The first place to look would be for traces of the previous CF under the IIS "Handler Mappings" and "ISAPI Filters" configuration, potentially at the server-level node if this was configured for all IIS sites. The link from Miguel is a good one. Another that might be useful is https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2016/10/removing-corrupt-connector-dependencies-from-iis/ As a last resort uninstall CF+IIS +reinstall both!

Answer (score 0):

We got the error message **All the IIS sites are already configured by some other version of ColdFusion.** when switched to another Coldfusion version. We tried many of the solutions which didn't work out for us.

Finally, we uninstalled IIS windows feature entirely(we were able to do that since it was a dev machine) restarted as prompted, and installed IIS feature again which resolved the problem.